# CSS quotes Property: Can it be used for any element?

Tags: html, css

[W3Schools shows](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_quotes.asp) this example for CSS quotes property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
q:lang(en)
{
quotes: "«" "»" "'" "'";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><q>This is a <q>big</q> quote.</q></p>
<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports the quotes property only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My doubt is, can the `quotes` property be used for any element other than `<blockquote>` and `<q>`? (I would like to use it to show links distinctly in my print stylesheet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the official W3C page: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#quotes-specify

While the `quotes` property can be applied to all elements, the `<q>` element is the only element that has support for it - by default.
Example:

```
q, span {quotes: "«" "»" "'" "'";}
```

```
<span>Just a span</span>
<q>and a q</q>
```

As you can see (in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Z26/)), only the q gets the quotes.

However, you can use another style property, `content`, by which you can tell any element you want to use those quotes!
Example:

```
q, span {quotes: "«" "»" "'" "'";}
span:before {content:open-quote;}
span:after {content:close-quote;}
```

```
<span>Just a span</span>
<q>and a q</q>
```

and you'll see (in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Z26/1/)) that the span also gets the quote marks now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Consequently, if you want to add characters before and after links, you could (with the usual CSS Caveats) do that directly using generated content, instead of using the quotes concept. For example, `:link:before, :visited:before { content: "→"; }`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sure! But the beautiful thing about the `quotes` concept is that you can have different quotes for different languages with the same `:before` and `:after` syntax. For instance, in my language it would be `q:lang(nl) { quotes: '„' '”' "‚" "’" }`

Answer (score 0):

IMO no. There are only for blockqotes / q tags. But you can simply check it ;)